# How do I clean my ThinkPad's keyboard and palm rest?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, cleaning

I have a Lenovo W500 and the keyboard and palm rest are getting dirty and shiny. Pedantic as I am, I'd like to clean it. I read that disassembling and removing those parts is easy. I couldn't find how to do it, so if someone can write how I should do it or point me to a guide somewhere I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The casing getting shiny is erosion. Cleaning will not help it.

Comment: Pedantic as *I* am, I'd like to point out that this is not what the word "pedantic" means ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately IBM/Lenovo is really good at writing hardware manuals.
http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-70068.html

This one is no exception.
Have fun taking it apart.

Answer (score 0):

I've used WD 40 on my macbook.  It cleans very well, and leves your computer looking like it just got "Armor All'd"

This will not make your computer look matte again like it seems you want.  Alcohol would probably work better for that.